Symfony Form with special characters
I have a Symfony 6.4 Webapp and using the Form Builder.
This is working perfectly, but I have an external data source. (Active Directory)
If the form have to load an entry with special characters (in german we have "ä" "ö" "ü" and so on), I get an exception.

The name group_with_special_characters contains illegal characters. Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":").

This is my code in the FormularType:
class AssignedGroupsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        foreach ($options['assignedGroups'] as $groupName => $groupDN) {
            $builder->add($groupName, CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => $groupName,
                'value' => $groupDN,
                'required' => false,
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => null,
        ]);

        $resolver->setDefined(['assignedGroups']);
    }
}

On the GitHub Project Page I found a closed issue with the possible solution to set 'expanded' => false, but this didn't work. Because we live in 2024 and I want to create a modern Web App I can't accept to convert the characters from "ö" to "oe", "ä" to "ae" and so on.
The base.html.twig template starts with
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
[...]


Remove or convert the german special chars before you assign them.
